# how to run multiple commands (nested control statements) on remote machines with sudo?

Tags: ssh, bash, remote-access

My bash code is:

```
  1 #!/bash/sh
  2 set -e
  3 USER="admin"
  4 HOST="1.2.3.4"
  5 PASSWORD="$(cat password.txt)"
  6 
  7 sshpass -p"$PASSWORD" ssh -t $USER@$HOST "/usr/bin/sudo bash -c 'sudo ls 2>&1; echo \"testing\";sudo ls src 2>&1;exit;'" >> log.txt
  8 
  9 echo "------------------------------Another Method ----------------------------------------"
 10 sshpass -p"$PASSWORD" ssh -t $USER@$HOST << EOF
 11 echo "....1...."
 12 sudo ls 2>&1
 13 echo "....2...."
 14 ls src 2>&1
 15 sudo echo "....3...."
 16 exit
 17 EOF
```

Line 7 can run multiple commands with sudo and print info to log.txt, Line 9-> Line 17 cannot. But I prefer to use Line9 to 17, because the commands I would like to run may contain nested control statements (such as if-else-fi). I have no idea how to do it in line 7. How to make line 9 to line 17 run multiple commands with sudo and print to local log.txt?

Part of screen output is:

```
....1....
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: pam_authenticate: User not known to the underlying authentication module
....2....
tmp
....3....
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Would [expect(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) be useful to you ?

Comment: create is bash script, copy it to the remote machine and run it there. Doing such harakiri is not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be unaware that you can add `>> log.txt` after the first `EOF`.

```
sshpass -p"$PASSWORD" ssh -t $USER@$HOST <<'EOF' >>log.txt
 echo "....1...."
 sudo ls 2>&1
 : etc     
EOF
```

You can put in the same commands in both variants (newline or semicolon separated) though proper quoting is slightly harder in the first case (not in the second! Though I added quotes around `'EOF'` to prevent the shell from interpolating variables etc in the here document; if you need the shell to do that, you'll need to revert that change).